# Scanner - Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found

Tags: java, file-io, lzw

There is definitely a line but I don't understand why cant the Scanner see it ..

Here is the beginning of the file :

```
256
<Y 1874>
<A T. HARDY‡<T Madding Crowd(Peuœ‚978)”C i”P 51‡DESCRIPTION OF FMERÅAK -- AÄINCIºNT
```

Below is my code for getting it:

```
File file = new File ("calgary/book1_enc");
Scanner first_line = new Scanner(file);
int size_st;
size_st = Integer.valueOf(first_line.nextLine());
```

But I am getting the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
    at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Unknown Source)
    at LZWDecoder.main(LZWDecoder.java:26)
```

The file book1_enc is an output of my LZW encoding algorithm.When I am passing the file to my Decoder I would like the decoder to know the size of dictionary which is 256 in this case...Thanks for reading...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the encoding of the input file. Use the [other constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner%28java.io.File,%20java.lang.String%29) for `Scanner` that specifies a character set:

```
Scanner first_line = new Scanner(file, "UTF-8");
```

Using other constructors results in the default character set being used which typically cannot correctly read unicode characters.

Workaround:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("book1_enc.dat"));
int sizeSt = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
```

Comment: Tested & worked here. You could try saving the file as in a text editor such as Eclipse or Notepad++ that lets you modify the encoding.

Comment: I open the file notepad++ and the first 3 lines are like I copied, I saved it as text file from Notepad++ and still having the same error, I created a text file and pasted the first 3 lines in this new text file, still having the same error, on the other hand the text file I saved as, does not look like  in Notepad++ has no "\n" all texts are sticked together, how did you try?Can you please elaborate or maybe send me the file you tried?

Comment: Copied the file contents from the question. Code is exactly the same as yours except for the change above. Without it I get `NoSuchElementException`

Comment: I created a new file Notepad++ copied my text from question, saved the new file as .txt file and added your suggestion "UTF-8", now with me it also works, but is there no way to make this work without opening with Notepad++ and then saving as.. can you please try this file http://www.file-upload.net/download-7763286/book1_enc.html

Comment: Scanner seems to be having a hard time doing a match on the unicode, you could use a `BufferedReader` instead

Answer (score 0):

It means that your file doesn't have next line. You should always check *hasNextLine()* before calling *nextLine*. You should modify your code like this

```
if (first_line.hasNextLine()){
    size_st = Integer.valueOf(first_line.nextLine());
}
```

*[java.util.NoSuchElementException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/NoSuchElementException.html)* is thrown by the *nextElement* method of an Enumeration to indicate that there are no more elements in the enumeration.

Comment: I think you meant `hasNextLine()`?

Comment: @VaibhavRaj I tried what you said before asking the question but when I do like that no single line is being passed but I want to get the first line and I know there is a first line I pasted the first 3 lines of my file as you can see in the question.